# Solve namespace collision for pod dependency

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I have a CocoaPod that has AFNetworking as a dependency (current version is 2.6.3).
At the same time I want to use RestKit which still uses AFNetworking 1.3.0.
Is there a "sane" way of mangling my AFNetworking symbols so that they don't conflict with RestKit?

Example podspec file snippet:
`s.dependency  'JSONModel', '~> 1.1'
 s.dependency  'tolo','~> 1.0'
 s.dependency  'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'`

In another project, I have:
`pod 'RestKit'
 pod 'MyLibrary'`

The result:
`[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- 'AFNetworking (= 1.3.4)' required by 'Podfile.lock'
- 'AFNetworking (~> 2.0)' required by 'MyLibrary (2.0)'`

I've also tried using [CocoaPods packager](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager) but without success. The dependencies of `MyLibrary` for some reason are not included in the mangled framework.

I've also tried to mangle only AFNetworking, but again no success as I can't point to a local dependency in the podspec file (!?).

Answer (score 1):

If your using `RestKit` in your project you can't use `AFNetworking 2.x` as `RestKit` is tightly integrated with `AFNetworking 1.3.x`  Your options are to use `AFNetworking 2.x` and remove `RestKit` from your `Podfile` or use `RestKit` and remove your dependencies for `AFNetworking 2.x`  A quick google search for `AFNetworking` 2.x vs `RestKit` should bring up a lot of articles covering the subject.  I hope my comments help you out.

Comment: True, it seems this is a somewhat hot topic of discussion. I am stubborn and I'am still trying to make it work with CocoaPods packager. 
In theory it should be possible to include both AFNetworking 2.x and 1.x, by "mangling" the symbols of one (practically invalidating the `duplicate symbols for architecture` error).
Thanks for your input!

Comment: no problemo, let me know what you decide to go with, as I am still using `RestKit` in my app, but I might make the switch to `AFNetworking 2.x` ...just haven't done much research on the subject yet.

Comment: What I'm doing so far:
1. Create my pod with AFNetworking 2.x
2. pod package my pod and create a "folder" from it
3. Use the resulting folder (which contains my library as a framework) as the pod source in the second project (like: 
`pod "MyLibrary", :path => 'MyLibrary/'
pod 'RestKit'`